# How do you make an equation in swift with multiple variables?

Tags: swift, variables, equation

I am trying to make something and I am trying to use an equation in Swift. This is the equation:

```
((((((((((calculation.d/100)/2) * Int(0.98) * (sqrt(calculation.vbottle * 1005.967 * (calculation.psi + (calculation.psi * (calculation.vbottle - (calculation.vol/1000))/2)/2)  * ((((calculation.d/100)/2) * Int(0.98) * (sqrt(calculation.vbottle * 1005.967 * (calculation.psi + (calculation.psi * (calculation.vbottle - (calculation.vol/1000))/2)/2) /1005.967 * (3.14159 * ((d / 100)/2) * ((d / 100)/2)))) - (((calculation.mempty/1000) + ((calculation.vol * 0.972)/1000))/2) * calculation.g) / (((calculation.mempty/1000) + ((calculation.vol * 0.972)/1000))/2)) * ((1005.967 * (calculation.vol / 1000000) / (((calculation.d/100)/2) * Int(0.98) * (sqrt(calculation.vbottle * 1005.967 * (calculation.psi + (calculation.psi * (calculation.vbottle - (calculation.vol/1000))/2)/2) * 6894.76))))) * 2) sin 2(calculation.theta) / calculation.g) * (1 - calculation.dc))
```

This might seem complicated but if you understand it, it isn't (for a computer). All the variables have been defined and the error message says:

Missing argument for parameter 'verbatim' in call and another error that says: Unterminated string literal

I am unsure why and whenever I google it up, an actual result never comes up and when one does, it's always about Playgrounds, not the actual Swift that is used to make apps and stuff.

EDIT:

Here is the reproducible example:

'''

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  MRE File
//
//  Created by Go Peter on 2021/06/18.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Calculation {
    var vbottle:Int = 2
    var g:Int = Int(9.807)
    var vol:Int = 250
    var d:Int = 2
    var theta:Int = 90
    var psi:Int = 40
    var mempty:Int = 70
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(((((((((((calculation.d/100)/2) * Int(0.98) * (sqrt(calculation.vbottle * 1005.967 * (calculation.psi + (calculation.psi * (calculation.vbottle - (calculation.vol/1000))/2)/2)  * ((((calculation.d/100)/2) * Int(0.98) * (sqrt(calculation.vbottle * 1005.967 * (calculation.psi + (calculation.psi * (calculation.vbottle - (calculation.vol/1000))/2)/2) /1005.967 * (3.14159 * ((d / 100)/2) * ((d / 100)/2)))) - (((calculation.mempty/1000) + ((calculation.vol * 0.972)/1000))/2) * calculation.g) / (((calculation.mempty/1000) + ((calculation.vol * 0.972)/1000))/2)) * ((1005.967 * (calculation.vol / 1000000) / (((calculation.d/100)/2) * Int(0.98) * (sqrt(calculation.vbottle * 1005.967 * (calculation.psi + (calculation.psi * (calculation.vbottle - (calculation.vol/1000))/2)/2) * 6894.76))))) * 2) sin 2(calculation.theta) / calculation.g) * (1 - calculation.dc)))m")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: where have you written this code?

Comment: I have written it in an .swift file in Xcode.

Comment: Good. But every code is written in .swift file but where? in function, in class??? where?

Comment: I have it written in a Text command as a string interpolation (I think that is what you call this \(variable).)in a struct and all the variables are defined in another calculation struct.

Comment: Please show actual code, not excerpts. You want help? You need to provide enough code for us to get into the exact same predicament you are in: no more but no less. Please read [mcve] and think about it.

Comment: Oh. Ok. Will comment again.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question and post your code there

Comment: I have the code in the question but the error changed too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors I see:

1. You need a space in `/1005.967` after the `/` operator -- there are likely other spots like this as well.
2. Near the end of the expression, you have a floating `sin` that doesn't have an operator before it and isn't followed with parenthesis at all
3. There are many spots where you refer to just `d`, but probably mean `calculation.d`
4. You have a mismatched number of open and closed parenthesis.
5. You don't actually have a `Calculation` property defined on your view, so there's nothing to do the calculations on yet.

Because I don't know the intent of some of this stuff, I can't actually fix it for you. But, I'd recommend trying to clean up the code a little -- at the least, it'll make it easier to debug.

To start, move this out of the interpolated `String` and into a computed property:

```
var calc : Int { //Int? -- see comment about this
  //your calculation here
} 

var body: some View {
  Text("\(calc)m")
}
```

Then, I'd break the calculation up into *much* smaller expressions that are more readable and would let you find your errors more easily than trying to sift through so many parenthesis, etc. Even a computer can theoretically handle a long, tough-to-read expression, it makes it a challenging debugging issue for us humans.

I'd also be really surprised if you truly want `Int` for these properties. You have a bunch of spots where you're doing things like `Int(0.98)`, which doesn't make sense, because it'll get rounded to `1`. Perhaps you instead want to use `Double` or `Float` for everything? You'll see as you start breaking the instructions up and the compiler starts to find more errors once it can parse everything correctly that you're going to end up with type mismatches between things like Int and Double in the existing expressions.

Comment: Thank you! You probably saved my code from being turned into useless lines of code!

Comment: That `2` after `sin` is probably supposed to be "squared".

Comment: "Then, I'd break the calculation up into much smaller expressions that are more readable and *more debuggable*" (I rephrase the italic part), that's the most important part of the answer! The rest is about bug fix. Not "way of doing code".

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions and feedback!